# TYPO3 BE permissions with two groups on same tree/page

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I'm looking for a way to simply manage permissions in TYPO3 with two groups on the same tree/page.

I have this simple tree page :

```
- Root
    - Page1
        - Subpage1
    - Page2
        - Subpage2
```

Group1 must have access to all pages from Root with edit access

Group2 must have access to Subpage1 and Subpage2 with reading access

I can only assign one group at a time to a page for permissions, how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the pages' group to "Group1" with write-permissions on all pages and
allow read access for others.

Mount only the Subpage1 and Subpage2 for the Group2 (db-mounts)

Comment: Awesome. I missed the "other" option. Rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using [be_acl](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/be_acl) extension you can set many permissions for many users/groups for each page.